# Refactoring Essentials vs. Resharper

Tags: visual-studio, refactoring, resharper, visual-studio-2015

I'm currently using Resharper heavily in my work. Recently I've heard that with Visual Studio 2015 there's a new product available called *Refactoring Essentials*.

My question is that how much of Resharper refactorings are available in *Refactoring Essentials*? How does it compare to Resharper in performance aspects?

The most important refactorings for me:

- Convert to Linq
- Extract Base Class
- Introduce [Variable, Parameter, Field, Property]
- Extract Method

Also I wanted to know if it supports languages other than .NET like *JavaScript*, *TypeScript*, *CSS*, ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Refactoring Essentials tools do not work with languages other than C# and VB - they rely on Roslyn, which only works with those languages. See [this page for a comparison between VS2015 and ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/comparisonMatrix_R9_vs2015.html) (note that this is a JetBrains product site). I don't think anyone's done anything similar with Refactoring Essentials.

Comment: The link you shared, that's the exact comparison I need.

Comment: I agree ReSharper has more features, and can be customized to your coding preferences, but the link you provide is a page made by JetBrains. So it's obviously going to make ReSharper look better.

Comment: Fair point. ReSharper is a more mature product and therefore does have more features, so the link isn't misrepresenting anything, but I have edited the answer to show that the link is to a JetBrains site.

Comment: Also, it's not a fair comparison since the JetBrains matrix only includes plain VS2015 built-in functionality, doesn't include [Refactoring Essential functionality](http://vsrefactoringessentials.com/Features/All).

Answer (score 1):

Refactoring Essentials only support C# and Visual Basic.

As far as your list of features is concerned, none of these are available:

- Convert to Linq
- Extract Base Class
- Introduce parameter

Introduce variable and field are available in a very basic form.

Extract Method is available, although it's not as feature-reach as ReSharper implementation.

There's a review that looks into most frequently used refactorings and some issues that one may encounter with this extension: [Review of Refactoring Essentials extension for Visual Studio](https://nimblegecko.com/review-of-refactoring-essentials-extension-for-visual-studio/)